# How can I instruct my non-technical users to reliably generate a system spec report?

Tags: windows, windows-10, diagnostic

We are building a resource-intensive software application for users who are not particularly expert computer users. Often, their typical office PCs are not up to our minimum spec especially GPU.

We never found a really error-proof way to ask them what their spec is - CPU, RAM, GPU, OS, hard-disk primarily (drivers would be awesome if possible).

We cannot ask them to install software to get this information and in a perfect world, they wouldn't have to do anything other than save the report as a file and email it.

What tools supplied with Windows can we standardise on? We used to use dxdiag.exe 10 years ago, is this still a good option?

Comment: Put the diagnostic in the app, then they just need to press the right button. i work support on a structure that does just that.

Comment: It's an idea except it is additional development time, and sometimes our app won't run up at all since it has various dependencies through 3rd-party libraries on OpenGL, etc.

Comment: BTW is this not on-topic for SU? Seems like it should be - an easy way to obtain system spec reliably.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - You are currently asking us to recommend tools.  There are dozens of way to generate a report like this.  Most of those tools won't indicate if you are missing a requirement like (Visual C++ Redistributable) though.  If you need specific information, write a program, that gathers the information and generates an email template.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys to get a run box, then type in `msinfo32` and hit ok, once it opens up do a “File > Export,” this will generate a text file with that information.